# Importing module in same folder triggers red underline error in PyCharm, but still works. What's the deal?

Tags: python, pycharm

BACKGROUND: I am working my way through the Python course 100 Days of Code by Angela Yu. I am a beginner programmer.

ISSUE: Every time I try to import a module from within the same folder PyCharm triggers a red underline error. It tells me that there is "no module name module_name.py", but when I run the code it still works. I can still import variables, lists, dictionaries, etc. So why the red line? Please see PICTURE for reference.

PICTURE: "main_classes_objects_turtle_1.py" and "another_module.py" are in the same folder.

[image]

WHAT I'VE TRIED: I read somewhere that I should mark the directory I'm working in as "source root", but that only fixes the problem for that folder. The problem still occurs in other folders.

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE: I found a workaround for the problem. If I add the full path name, it works:

```
import folder.sub_folder.another_module as am
```

I didn't know this was something I could do until tonight.

Comment: All I can guess is, something went wrong during Pycharm's indexing process, maybe this will help? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/invalidate-caches.html

Comment: @Icyvapor Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately I'm not sure I have a sufficient understanding of PyCharm or coding to see how this might solve my problem.  I will give the page another read to see if anything jumps out at me.

Comment: And where is `another_module`? What is the directory structure? This is possibly because the current module is inside a directory that is not a package and `another_module` is not imported properly yet found in the working dir. a proper form would be `from some_package.another_module import whatever`